# docker - php - permisos

Tags: php, bash, docker, docker-compose

Estoy programando un servidor web usando xammp y al subirlo a producción donde uso docker me he encontrado con este problema:

```
2021/04/28 08:58:19 [crit] 15#15: *4 open() "/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body/0000000001" failed (13: Permission denied), client: XXX, server: , request: "POST /admin/data/test.php HTTP/1.1", host: "XXX", referrer: "https://XXX/admin/data/othercsv.php"
```

He entrado en el docker usando "sh" y he cambiado los permisos con `chmod -R 755 /var/lib/nginx` y a funcionado perfectamente. después he visto que con `chgrp -R nginx /var/lib/nginx` también funcionaba.

Así que he ido a mi `docker-compose.yaml` y he añadido la linea  `command: bash -c "chgrp -R nginx /var/lib/nginx";` obteniendo un error 502 en toda la web, he probado con todo lo que se me ha pasado por la cabeza y con lo de google también, incluso `entrypoint: [ "sh", "-c", "sleep 10 && chgrp -R nginx /var/lib/nginx"]` y `command: [sh, -c, "chmod -R 755 /var/lib/nginx";]`. También cargando archivos externos con los comandos e intentando ejecutarlos externamente. Pero no he tenido suerte.

Código en docker-compose:

```
  nginx_web:
    image: tobi312/php:8.0-fpm-nginx-alpine
    hostname: XXX
    restart: always
    expose:
      - "80"
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/XXX:/var/www/html:rw
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=XXX
      - LETSENCRYPT_HOST=XXX
      - LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL=XXX
      - ENABLE_NGINX_REMOTEIP=1
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    depends_on:
       - mongodb
       - nginx-proxy
```

(Estoy usando docker proxy)
Cualquier ayuda se agradece!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución vino del creador de la imagen de la ventana acoplable. Su solución fue `chown -R www-data:www-data /var/lib/nginx/*`. Directamente en docker.

Seguiré buscando formas de incluir comandos en docker-compose

[Link a la Issue](https://github.com/Tob1asDocker/php/issues/2)